# Firefox и подгрузка картинок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброго времени всем!

Есть html файл в котором прописано 200 img src, по 400 кб каждая. Все эти картинки используются при скролле, для бекграунда на position:fixed.

Данный код отлично работает в Chrome и Safari, но в Firefox'e, происходит эффект загрузки картинки, то есть, на миллисекунду появляется белый экран :)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то убить эту противную подгрузку картинок, без уменьшения качества фоток?

1. Есть html:

   ```
   <div id="container">
    <img src="1.jpg" class="animated" />
    <img src="2.jpg" class="animated" />
    ...
    <img src="200.jpg" class="animated" />
    </div>
   ```
2. Есть js:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {

       var pictureCount = $('#container img').length;
       var scrollResolution = 50;

       animateHorse();

       function animateHorse() {
           var currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
           var imageIndex = Math.round(currentScrollPosition / scrollResolution);

           if (imageIndex >= pictureCount) {
               imageIndex = pictureCount - 1; // Select last image
           }

           $("#container img").hide();
           $("#container img").eq(imageIndex).show();
       }

       $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       animateHorse();
       });
   });
   ```

Попробовал ещё подрубить этот скрипт: `scrollmagic.io/examples/expert/image_sequence.html` и пропала белая подгрузка, но сайт начал жутко тормозить :[

Comment: Пробовали предварительную загрузку картинок?